# xlwings: xlwings.conf in working directory and in sheet not working

Tags: xlwings

I created a test project using the xlwings quickstart and wanted to use the xlwings.conf file in the same working directory. However it doesn't want to take anything from that file and always load the default from the users home directory in .xlwings/xlwings.conf.

I tried having the xlwings.conf in the same directory as the excel workbook and it won't load the settings from there.

I also tried using the xlwings.conf as a sheet in the workbook itself but it also doesn't work.

WHen I make changes via the ribbon, they are also always applied on the config in the user directory, never to the one in the same workbook directory.

Any help would be appreciated.